# Room - find sum of objects by string?

Tags: android, android-room

I have problem with queries in Room. I have entity where is String field called Type. I want to make a query that will allow me to get the sum of objects by type. So if I have 4 expenses with Bills type I want to get them as a sum.

Expense:

```
@Entity(tableName = "expense_table")
public class Expense  {

@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
private int expenseId;
private String note;
private Double value;
private String type;
```

Table of defined types:

```
private String[] expenses = {"Bills", "Car", "Child", "Clothes", "Entertainment", "Education", "Electronics",
        "Food", "Health", "Home", "Pet", "Shopping", "Transport", "Travel", "Others"};
```

Query in Dao:

```
@Query("SELECT SUM(value) FROM expense_table GROUP BY type")
LiveData<List<Double>> getTotalType();
```

In query above I'm getting the sum of every single type, but I do not know which one is which. I need this information because I want to set sum of types in chart. So my question is: Is it possible to make one query to get every single sum with name of type, or rather I need to make every query for every single type?

Comment: Also add the type in the query "SELECT type,SUM(value) FROM expense_table GROUP BY type".

Comment: Unfortunately error: The query returns some columns [type, SUM(value)] which are not used by java.lang.Double.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the type to your query and create a POJO to hold both values(the type and its corresponding total):

```
@Query("SELECT type, SUM(value) as total FROM expense_table GROUP BY type")
LiveData<List<TypeWithSum>> getTotalType();
```

where TypeWithSum is:

```
public class TypeWithSum {
   private String type;
   private double total;

   public TypeWithSum(String type, double total) {
       this.type = type;
       this.total = total;
   }
}
```

Comment: Probably you have right. I'll check it soon because I'm little busy.